# How to set cmake generator back to default Unix Makefiles?

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, ninja

I am using cmake3.20.0 with wsl2+vscode+Intel oneapi to build my Fortran project. Nearly for some reason I reinstalled ninja, but it seems my CMake generator has been changed to ninja, not by default Unix Makefiles. I tried to use the command

```
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefiles")
message("generator is set to ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}")
```

in CMakeLists.txt, also cleared the whole "build" dir with CMakeCache.txt in it. When I reconfigure the project, it shows

> [cmake] generator is set to Unix Makefiles

but the "Executing command" line still shows "-G Ninja" at the end and there still generates a build.ninja file in "build" dir instead of MakeFile.
How can I set generator back to Unix Makefile?

Comment: Are you calling `cmake` yourself or is some other tool or script involved?

Comment: @usr1234567 I am using the vscode extension [cmake](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools), and it is inconvenient to add cmake parameters myself.

Comment: This makes it more a vs code question then a CMake question. Reading its documentation, I am not sure whether any generator beside Ninja is supported or advised: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/master/docs/configuring.rst#id4

Comment: You cannot set the generator from within the CMakeLists.txt file.  It needs to be set on the command line when invoking cmake, or in the environment before invoking cmake.  See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html